# Mysql name as based of of value

Tags: mysql, join, if-statement

I am trying to join tables together but I cannot figure out how to join the fields as different names based off of a value.
For example

```
SELECT
     ms_workorder_events.start AS workStart // IF the value of workorder_events.eventType = 1
     ms_workorder_events.start AS qaStart // IF the value of workorder_events.eventType = 2
FROM 
  workorders
  LEFT JOIN ms_workorder_events 
  ON 
    workorders.workOrderID=ms_workorder_events.workOrderID
```

I have been working on this for a while and cannot figure it out.

Comment: `SELECT
organizations.organizationName, 
owner.firstName AS ownerFirstName,
owner.lastName AS ownerLastName,
assigned.firstName AS assignedFirstName,
assigned.lastName AS assignedLastName,
qa.firstName AS QAFirstName,
qa.lastName AS QALastName,
workorders.title, 
workordertypes.type,
statuses.status,
workorders.statusDate,
MAX(CASE WHEN ms_workorder_events.eventType = 1 THEN ms_workorder_events.start ELSE NULL END) AS workStart,
MAX(CASE WHEN ms_workorder_events.eventType = 2 THEN ms_workorder_events.start ELSE NULL END) AS qaStart,
workorders.targetDate`

Comment: `FROM workorders
LEFT JOIN users AS owner ON workorders.owner=owner.userID
LEFT JOIN users AS assigned ON workorders.assignedTo=assigned.userID
LEFT JOIN users AS qa ON workorders.qa=qa.userID
LEFT JOIN organizations ON workorders.organizationID=organizations.organizationID
LEFT JOIN workordertypes ON workorders.typeID=workordertypes.workOrderTypeID
LEFT JOIN statuses ON workorders.statusID=statuses.statusID
LEFT JOIN ms_workorder_events ON workorders.workOrderID=ms_workorder_events.workOrderID


WHERE workorders.owner ='8'
AND workorders.workOrderID > 12579`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically what you are asking for is a type of pivot query.

The trick here is to use a `CASE` which will provide the column value when the condition matches or `NULL` if not, then use an aggregate function like `MAX()` to collapse the nulls into a single row:

```
  SELECT
    MAX(CASE WHEN ms_workorder_events.start = 1 THEN ms_workorder_events.start ELSE NULL END) AS workStart
    MAX(CASE WHEN ms_workorder_events.start = 2 THEN ms_workorder_events.start ELSE NULL END) AS qaStart
  FROM
    workorders
    LEFT JOIN ms_workorder_events ON workorders.workOrderID = ms_workorder_events.workOrderID
```

To ensure more than one row is returned, you will need more columns in the `SELECT` list and an appropriate `GROUP BY` clause. For example:

```
  SELECT
    /* Retrieve row per workOrderID, for example */
    workorder.workOrderID,
    MAX(CASE WHEN ms_workorder_events.start = 1 THEN ms_workorder_events.start ELSE NULL END) AS workStart
    MAX(CASE WHEN ms_workorder_events.start = 2 THEN ms_workorder_events.start ELSE NULL END) AS qaStart
  FROM
    workorders
    LEFT JOIN ms_workorder_events ON workorders.workOrderID = ms_workorder_events.workOrderID
  GROUP BY workorder.workOrderID
```

### Update

To incorporate the above into your full query, it is recommended to `LEFT JOIN` it in as a derived table.  In this case, a join is not needed in the subquery, and it can be done on `ms_workorder_events` alone since it joins `workorders` in the outer query.

Here's an abbreviated example:

```
SELECT
  organizations.organizationName, 
  owner.firstName AS ownerFirstName,
  /* ... Snip all other columns... */
  workorders.title,
  workorders.workOrderId,
  /* ... Snip all other columns... */
  /* Columns from subquery join */
  eventType.workStart,
  eventType.qaStart
FROM
  workorders 
  LEFT JOIN users AS owner ON workorders.owner=owner.userID
  /* ...Snip all your other joins...*/
  LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT
      workOrderID,
      MAX(CASE WHEN ms_workorder_events.start = 1 THEN ms_workorder_events.start ELSE NULL END) AS workStart
      MAX(CASE WHEN ms_workorder_events.start = 2 THEN ms_workorder_events.start ELSE NULL END) AS qaStart
    FROM ms_workorder_events
    GROUP BY workorder.workOrderID
  ) eventType ON workorders.workOrderId = eventType.workOrderId
/* Etc... */
```

Comment: The only problem I am having now is that it is only returning one row, I only need to collapse the two matches

Comment: @Shikoru Then you need to select more columns and add a `GROUP BY`.  update pending above...

Answer (score 0):

This can also be done by joining on the `ms_workorder_events` multiple times. The syntax would be similar to this:

```
select 
  we1.start workStart,
  we2.start as qaStart
from workorders w
LEFT JOIN ms_workorder_events we1
  ON w.workOrderID=we1.workOrderID
  and we1.eventType = 1 
LEFT JOIN ms_workorder_events we2
  ON w.workOrderID=we2.workOrderID
  and we2.eventType = 1
```

So the full query would be:

```
SELECT o.organizationName, 
  owner.firstName AS ownerFirstName, 
  owner.lastName AS ownerLastName, 
  assigned.firstName AS assignedFirstName, 
  assigned.lastName AS assignedLastName, 
  qa.firstName AS QAFirstName, 
  qa.lastName AS QALastName, 
  w.title, 
  w.type, 
  s.status, 
  w.statusDate, 
  we1.start workStart, 
  we2.start as qaStart, 
  w.targetDate
FROM workorders w
LEFT JOIN users AS owner 
  ON w.owner=owner.userID 
LEFT JOIN users AS assigned 
  ON w.assignedTo=assigned.userID 
LEFT JOIN users AS qa 
  ON w.qa=qa.userID 
LEFT JOIN organizations o
  ON w.organizationID=o.organizationID 
LEFT JOIN workordertypes wot
  ON w.typeID=wot.workOrderTypeID 
LEFT JOIN statuses s
  ON w.statusID=s.statusID 
LEFT JOIN ms_workorder_events we1
  ON w.workOrderID=we1.workOrderID 
  and we1.eventType = 1 
LEFT JOIN ms_workorder_events we2
  ON w.workOrderID=we2.workOrderID 
  and we1.eventType = 2 
WHERE w.owner ='8' 
  AND w.workOrderID > 12579
```